# Cannot alter composite type because a column is using it

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to alter the attributes of a composite type that is currently being used by a column in a table.

I am using the command:

```
ALTER TYPE *typeName* ALTER ATTRIBUTE *attributeName* SET DATA TYPE text;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the error:

```
ERROR:  cannot alter type *typeName* because column *columnName* uses it
```

How would I go about doing this in a production environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must create a new type, change the columns that have that type and then rename the new type to de actual name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer