# Alter composite type that used in column as array of composite type

Tags: database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-migrations, composite-types

I have composite type in postgres

```
composite_type(numeric(10, 2), numeric(10, 3))
```

Table example

| id(serial) | comp(composite_type[]) |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |

I need to alter first attribute to numeric(12, 2). If I try to alter type manually, i have error:

```
Type can't be alter because it used in column
```

How I can alter this type without data loss?

**P.S. I use doctrine and symfony**

1. I try to alter type as in documentation
2. May be I need to create new type, then cast my column to it and then delete old type and rename new, but I don't know how to cast array of composite type.

Comment: Quite similar problem is listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852403/cannot-alter-composite-type-because-a-column-is-using-it

Comment: I saw this answer, but i want to know how to cast array of composite type